# Conditional Expectation as a function of X

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I hope someone can clear the doubt on conditional distribution, in a text, it mentions:

To interpret
the notation $f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)$, we need to be clear that there is nothing random about
the random variable $Y$, since it is already fixed. What remains is a sub-population distribution
in terms of $X$ (i.e. the reduced sample space of $\Omega_X$ where $Y$ happened). Consequently,
the conditional PMF/PDF $f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)$ is a distribution in terms of $X$.

I have no trouble understanding this, since conditional just means looking into the reduced sample space of $X$ where $Y$ has happened for a specific set. But soon after, when conditional expectation is mentioned, it says:

There are two points to note here. First, the expectation of $\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y=y]$ is taken with respect to $f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)$. We assume that the random variable $Y$ is already fixed at the state $Y=y$. Thus, the only source of randomness is $X$. Secondly, since the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y=y]$ has eliminated the randomness of $X$, the resulting function is in $y$.

A quick read online reveals that the expectation of $X$ given $Y$ can indeed be a function of $Y$ if we treat this conditional expectation as random variable. I am just slightly confused why the conditional expectation is not a function of $X$, since the underlying conditional distribution is a function of $X$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without getting very much into measure theory,consider the random vector $(X,Y)$ with density $f_{X,Y}(\cdot,\cdot)$ (wrt a dominating measure $\text d\mu(x,y)$) decomposed as
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_Y(y)\times f_{X|Y}(x|y)$$
where

- $f_Y(\cdot)$ is a probability density (wrt the appropriate dominating measure $\text d\mu_2(y)$) attached with the random variable $Y$
- $f_{X|Y}(\cdot|y)$ is a probability density (wrt the appropriate dominating measure $\text d\mu_1(x)$) for (almost) every $y\in\mathcal Y$, attached with a random variable $Z_y$. In this notation, $y$ is a parameter of the density.

For a fixed value of $y\in\mathcal Y$, $f_{X|Y}(\cdot|y)$ can thus be understood as a regular density over the set $\mathcal X$ and
$$f_{X|Y}(\cdot|y):\ x\longmapsto f_{X|Y}(x|y)$$
is a non-negative integrable (measurable) function on $\mathcal X$ such that
$$\int_\mathcal Xf_{X|Y}(x|y)\text d\mu_1(x)=1$$
This means that, for a fixed value of $y\in\mathcal Y$, the expectation of $Z_y\sim f_{X|Y}(\cdot|y)$ can considered and, provided it exists for this specific value of $y\in\mathcal Y$, be defined as
$$\mathbb E_y[X] = \int_\mathcal X xf_{X|Y}(x|y)\text d\mu_1(x)\tag{1}$$
It is usually written as $\mathbb E[X|Y=y]$. In the event (1) exists for *all* values of $y\in\mathcal Y$, the function
$$\varphi:\ y \longmapsto \mathbb E[X|Y=y]$$
is rigorously defined. It can therefore be called to transform the *random variable* $Y$ into the new random variable $\varphi(Y)$. It is usually written as $\mathbb E[X|Y]$ and is equal to (1) when the realisation of $Y$ is equal to $y$.

As seen above, this *random variable* $\varphi(Y)=\mathbb E[X|Y]$ is not a function of the *random variable* $X$, even though they may be correlated with one another. Hence, the citation

> First, the expectation *of* $\mathbb E[X∣Y=y]$ is taken with respect to $f_{X∣Y}(x∣y)$. We assume that the random variable $Y$ is already fixed at the state $Y=y$. Thus, the only source of randomness is $X$.

should be restated as [with highlighted changes]:

> First, the expectation $\mathbb E[X∣Y=y]$ is taken with respect *to the distribution with density* $f_{X∣Y}(x∣y)$. We assume that the random variable $Y$ is already *observed* at the *realisation* $Y=y$. Thus, the only *remaining* source of randomness *in the expectation* is $X$ *with distribution $f_{X∣Y}(\cdot∣y)$, that is, the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$.*

Similarly,

> Secondly, since the expectation $\mathbb E[X∣Y=y]$ has eliminated the randomness of $X$, the resulting function is in $y$.

should state

> Secondly, since the expectation $\mathbb E[X∣Y=y]$ has eliminated the *(remaining) conditional* randomness of $X$ *given $Y=y$*, the resulting function is *a function of* $y$.

Comment: Thanks for this rigorous explanation!

Comment: Thanks. This is rigourous and clarifies my doubt. From what you wrote, the PDF of $X$ given $Y$ is still a function of $X$ right? Just want to make sure that this is still true.

Comment: The pdf of the rv $X$ given thr rv $Y$ is the function $f_{X|Y}(⋅|⋅)$ and, therefore, is a function/mapping from $\mathcal X$ to $\mathbb R^+$ indexed by the realisation of $Y$ or $Y$ itself, but definitely *not* a function of the random variable $X$. (Just as the marginal density $f_X$ is *not* a function of $X$. It determines the distribution of $X$ and thus in a very informal sense depends on $X$, but it is not a mathematical *function* of the rv $X$.)

Answer (score 12):

If you take the expectation of $X$, it's not a function of $X$. You integrate $xf(x)$ over $x$, and so $x$ is gone, producing only a number.

If you take the expectation of $X|Y=y$, it's not a function of $X$. You integrate $xf(x|y)$ over $x$ (think of it as $xf(x)$ with a different $f(x)$ for different $y$), and so $x$ is gone, producing only a number, which may be different for different $y$s, hence a function of $y$.